# IndexError: while running generalized hough transform on my data, why?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, image-processing, hough-transform

I am trying to apply the [available generalized hough transform (GHT)](https://github.com/adl1995/generalised-hough-transform) on my own data. the program is running very well on the provided sample data, however, for my data once it reaches to [this line](https://github.com/adl1995/generalised-hough-transform/blob/master/match-table.py#L38) it is giving error:
My data has been saves into two numpy arrays in [main function](https://github.com/adl1995/generalised-hough-transform/blob/master/generalized-hough-demo.py#L16):

```
f = h5py.File(img_path,'r')  # reading the reference image
refim = f['image'].value
refim = np.asarray(refim)
refim[refim!=1]=0 
#im = imread('Input1.png')
f = h5py.File(im_path,'r')  # reading the image that should be matched
im = f['image'].value
im = np.asarray(im)
```

Reference and test image both has same size `256x256` and object center in reference image is `[ 83.02902047 127.19376853]`. The variable with the name of `table` is a list of with shape of `(90,)` in which each of the list elements has the shape of `(144,2)` tuples, for example one element includes  [-102.97097952712484, 12.193768525539397]

```
/home/user/anaconda2/envs/testcaffe/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/__init__.py:36: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
  from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "generalized-hough-demo.py", line 43, in <module>
    acc = matchTable(im, table)
  File "/home/user/workspace/jupyter_codes/PythonSIFT/Genarlized_Hough_Voting/generalised-hough-transform/match_table.py", line 38, in matchTable
    acc[vector[0]+x, vector[1]+y]+=1
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

I am struggling for two days, your expert opinion is really appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This error message states that the indices should be `only integers`. And as you can see, `table` is a list of `vectors` and each `vector` is a 2d-vector as you stated in the question.

So, `vector[0]` and `vector[1]` are mostly **float** and indices of a matrix must be integer. That's why it points the error at line **43**.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and help, but whenever I am saving the reference image from a `.mat` file , after calculating the object center, its coordinate is `[58.18447013896255 147.54025670945157]` , what do you suggest? why the position of non-zero points it is float values?

Comment: However, the problem is that during the finding the object center by this command `cx, cy = np.transpose(np.nonzero(refim)[::-1]).mean(axis=0) ` the output coordinate is, for example, `[58.18447013896255 147.54025670945157]` and other non zero coordinates in test image are also float when I am reading from a `.mat` file and save it in a numpy array. How to tackle this?

Comment: First, why is the center float?
Let's assume you have (21px, 21px) image, the center will be `cx=10` and `cy=10` right? What about (20px, 20px)?? what the center will be? Your code says it will be `cx=9.5` and `cy=9.5` which isn't right.. the center is either `10` or `9`.
How to solve that?
Simple, use casting like so `int(vector[0])` and `int(vector[1])`

Comment: Thank you very much, sorry I am not expert in python, and did not know why the positions are shown in float. I have mostly worked with Matlab and I was thinking if I convert the coordinates to int, I may be wrong. Thanks once again

Comment: May I ask you to mark my answer as the right answer?

Comment: Yes sure, sorry I forgot. Thanks once again